# Absolute effect size and relative effect size in HLM

Tags: multilevel-analysis, effect-size

I am having trouble figuring out what the regression equations for HLM models are with absolute effect size and relative effect size provided in a table.

E.g., the outcome variable is reading test score. The predictors in level one are:

- student gender (absolute effect: -0.05; relative effect: -0.06) and
- SES (absolute effect: 0.14; relative effect: -0.09).

The predictors in level two are:

- school mean SES (absolute effect: 0.05; relative effect: 0.06) and
- disciplinary climate (absolute effect: 0.07; relative effect: 0.07).

I am not very sure about what the HLM models are in this example.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you wondering what the regression equation for this model is?

Comment: Yes, I wonder what the regression equations for this model is. Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Please register & merge your accounts, @ellen. There is information on that [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Then you will be notified if something happens on your question & you will be able to respond to comments. Please do not use the "Your Answer" field to respond to comments, as that is only for answers.